# Java でPersonクラスにsetNameメソッドを追加したい

Tags: java

プログラミング 始めたばかりなので変なことを言っていたらすみません。

Personクラス（getNameメソッドとgetAgeメソッドは定義されている）に、新しくsetNameメソッドを追加したいのですが、戻り値なし（return使用不可）でどうやったらできますか？

Comment: 書きかけでも構わないので、実際のコードも質問に含めておくと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

> Personクラス（getNameメソッドとgetAgeメソッドは定義されている）

が次のような状態を言っているのであれば、

```java
public class Person {

  private String name;
  private int age;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }
}
```

次のようなコードになります。

```java
public class Person {

  private String name;
  private int age;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  // ここから追加部分

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

戻り値が無いことを示すのは `void` です。